# elasticsearch set sort order using querystring

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have the following simple elastisearch query:

```
http://localhost:9200/apn/presupuesto/_search?q=subcuenta:penal&sort=anio
```

And it works fine

Now I'm trying to order by anio desc. I tried with all these options:

```
...l&sort=anio desc

...l&sort=-anio

...l&sort=anio&order=desc
```

But none of them seemed to work

How can I achieve it? (ideally, from the querystring, without having to use a more complex query)

Comment: thanks a lot Diego, please enter it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: BTW, anybody knows how to order by several fields, like anio, cuenta, subcuenta??? from que querystring

Comment: @opensas: Just add more `sort` parameters. They will be applied in order given in URI.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try sort=anio:desc.

See  [search API - uri request](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/uri-request.html) for a list of parameters.

Comment: Godd Job Buddy,. Do you know if we can use a GroupBy in Query string ? 
Also i want to Count with GroupBy. is it possible ?

Comment: Link seems broken, check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-uri-request.html

Answer (score 18):

To answer opensas question

[elasticsearch set sort order using querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894553/elasticsearch-set-sort-order-using-querystring#comment19144440_13894553)

this feature is called as multilevel sorting.

Example query is

```
GET /_search
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query":   { "match": { "tweet": "manage text search" }},
            "filter" : { "term" : { "user_id" : 2 }}
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        { "date":   { "order": "desc" }},
        { "_score": { "order": "desc" }}
    ]
}
```

> Order is important. Results are sorted by the first criterion first. Only results whose first sort value is identical will then be sorted by the second criterion, and so on.
>   http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html#_multilevel_sorting

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of how to sort indices in Management -> Dev Tools:

```
GET _cat/indices?s=index:desc
```