# Elasticsearch - how insert sort mode in url

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

How I should sorting data in elasticsearch via URL ? I m find that [http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/13894553/elasticsearch-set-sort-order-using-querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894553/elasticsearch-set-sort-order-using-querystring) and this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html but it doesnt work.

I try add sort mode to the URL like this

```
/transaction/search?seller=335&size=10&page=502&sort=seller:asc
```

But got failure:

```
No mapping found for [seller:asc] in order to sort on
```

My mapping looks like:

```
{
    "all": {
        "mappings": {
            "auctions": {
                "_all": { "enabled": false }, 
                "properties": {
                    "cat": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "curr": { "index": "not_analyzed",  "store": true,  "type": "string" }, 
                    "end_date": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "price": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "start_date": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "tcat": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "title": { "store": true,  "type": "string" }, 
                    "uid": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }
                }
            }, 
            "trans": {
                "_all": { "enabled": false }, 
                "properties": {
                    "buyer": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "cat": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "comment_text": { "store": true,  "type": "string" }, 
                    "comment_type": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "item": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "price": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "seller": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "title": { "store": true,  "type": "string" }, 
                    "tree_cat": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "ts": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I must catch this sort and add in code or what?

I try do it from spring boot.

My method Controller looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auctions/search", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private Map search(
            @RequestParam(value = "categoryId", required = false) Long categoryId,
            @RequestParam(value = "treeCategoryId", required = false) Long treeCategoryId,
            @RequestParam(value = "currency", required = false) String currency,
            @RequestParam(value = "priceFrom", required = false) Long priceFrom,
            @RequestParam(value = "priceTo", required = false) Long priceTo,
            @RequestParam(value = "startDateFrom", required = false) Long startDateFrom,
            @RequestParam(value = "startDateTo", required = false) Long startDateTo,
            @RequestParam(value = "endDateFrom", required = false) Long endDateFrom,
            @RequestParam(value = "endDateTo", required = false) Long endDateTo,
            @RequestParam(value = "title", required = false) String title,
            @RequestParam(value = "uid", required = false) Long uid,
            Pageable pageable) {

        final AuctionIndexSearchParams searchParams = AuctionIndexSearchParams.builder()
                .categoryId(categoryId)
                .treeCategoryId(treeCategoryId)
                .currency(currency)
                .priceFrom(priceFrom)
                .priceTo(priceTo)
                .startDateFrom(startDateFrom)
                .startDateTo(startDateTo)
                .endDateFrom(endDateFrom)
                .endDateTo(endDateTo)
                .title(title)
                .uid(uid)
                .build();

        return auctionService.searchByIndexParams(searchParams, pageable);
    }
```

Service:

```
 public Map searchByIndexParams(AuctionIndexSearchParams searchParams, Pageable pageable) {
        final List<FilterBuilder> filters = Lists.newArrayList();
        final NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery());


        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("cat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCurrency()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("curr", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTreeCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("tcat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUid()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("uid", v))));

       final BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTitle()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.should(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getTitle()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("title"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).isPresent()
                && Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("start_date").from(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getStartDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).isPresent()
                && Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("end_date").from(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getEndDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).isPresent()
                && Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("price").from(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).to(searchParams.getPriceTo()));
        }

        searchQuery.withPageable(pageable);
        searchQuery.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder);

        FilterBuilder[] filterArr = new FilterBuilder[filters.size()];
        filterArr = filters.toArray(filterArr);
        searchQuery.withFilter(andFilter(filterArr));

        final FacetedPage<AuctionIndex> search = auctionIndexRepository.search(searchQuery.build());

        Map response = new HashMap(); 


        response.put("data", search.map(index ->auctionRepository.findAuctionById(Long.valueOf(index.getId()))).getContent());
        response.put("totalElements", search.getTotalElements());
        response.put("totalPages", search.getTotalPages());
        response.put("currentPage", search.getNumber());
        return response;

    }
```

Comment: Can you show the exact URL you're using? Are you querying via curl? Sense? As far as I can see there is no `/search` endpoint in ES and you're missing the `q=...` parameter in order to filter on `seller:335`.

Comment: I don't see where you use `size`, `page` and `sort` in your code, i.e. how does your `Pageable` instance look like?

Comment: I added that example line to the service: searchQuery.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("cat").order(SortOrder.ASC)); but it doesnt work result is the same like with out it.

Comment: Sorry after add this line I`v got error "Data too large, data for [cat] would be larger than limit"

Comment: Can you check if [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30814856/4604579) takes care of the problem?

Comment: That "indices.breaker.fielddata.limit: 75%" I should have in file elasticsearch.yml ? because I try find that line in file and it not exist.

Comment: Yes, you can add it at the end of the `elasticsearch.yml` file and restart ES.